# Include a calendar view and maintain the navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, calendar

in my iOS app I want to include a calendar view (Vurig Calendar) in a viewController. This is a screenshot from the view controller just before adding the calendar view
[image]

You can see there is a navigation bar and a tableview in the upper side of the view. 
Then, I include following code to the viewDidLoad method to show the calendar:

```
VRGCalendarView *calendario = [[VRGCalendarView alloc] init];
    calendario.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:calendario];
```

And now the calendar appears on the view, but the navigation bar disappears:
[image]
Please, tell me what to do to include the calendar view and the navigation bar.
Thank you in advance.

I have included the code proposed by @Balram Tiwari:

```
VRGCalendarView *calendario = [[VRGCalendarView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 330, 280)];
calendario.delegate=self;
[self.view addSubview:calendario];
```

[image]

1. Navigation bar appears as desired.
2. Calendar view is shown, but without month title and black colour instead of cells with days.
3. Navigation arrows don't work as expected.

Any idea how to solve the issues? I could put the needed code if useful....
Thank you, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any customization method in this calender control. So can just open the component's .m file `VRGCalendarView.m` and modify the init method.

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, YOUR_Y_COORDINATE, kVRGCalendarViewWidth, 0)]; 
...
...
}
```

This solution works.

Comment: Thank you @Balram Tiwari, I will check and implement your proposal, I will tell you later...

Comment: I have edited my question to add the results of your proposal. Thank you.

Comment: Your second proposal made it. Thank you @Bairam Tiwari.

Comment: Yes, I mean to say that, you open the component & then adjust Y component accordingly. I will edit the answer to reflect just the working solution.